# Excel nested if statement error how to fix?

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

trying to do a nested if :

```
=IF([Years of Service]>10,'Data Tables'!$B$11,"if([years of service]>5,'Data Tables'!$b$10)")
```

getting a spill error.

Comment: You should not have those double-quotes inside the formula, unless you want that literal string as the output.

Comment: this is the full formula i had to use: could you tell me why it still gives me the spill error? =IF([Years of Service]>10,'Data Tables'!$B$11,IF([Years of Service]>5,'Data Tables'!$B$10),IF([Years of Service]>1,'Data Tables'!$B$9,'Data Tables'!$B$8))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't indicate what you want to do and I'm not sure exactly what you really want to do.

But it seems your formula is within a **Table**. That being the case, formulas that output arrays, when placed in a **Table** will produce the `#SPILL!` error.

If, what you want to do, is to compare the Years of Service from the same row as the formula, then you need to refer just to that row, so as to not output an array.

eg:

```
=IF([@[Years of Service]]>10,'Data Tables'!$B$11,
IF([@[Years of Service]]>5,'Data Tables'!$B$10,
IF([@[Years of Service]]>1,'Data Tables'!$B$9,
'Data Tables'!$B$8)))
```

If you want something else, then you'll need to provide more detail.